# impact of including Workflow Manager in the new platform design

Tags: 2013, workflow-manager

Is there any impact of including Workflow Manager in the new platform design for sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 possible scenarios to install Workflow Manager for SharePoint farm :

1. Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTP. `(Impact Low Performance & Security)`
2. Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTPS.`(Impact Low Performance)`
3. Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is NOT part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTP.`(Impact High Cost & Security)`
4. Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is NOT part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTPS.`(Impact High Cost)`

Option 4 is the preferred solution to ensure **performance and security**.

**Note :** Building an independent Workflow Manager farm at least should be consist of one to three servers based on organization requirements and its budget capability.

For more details check [Install and Configure Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

A Workflow Manager Farm can run on one or three servers and shouldn't be installed on the SharePoint Farm. The only impact is that you can run Workflows, and that slightly more resources is consumed while you workflows are active. But not to the extent that it would make a significant difference for the overall performance of the SharePoint Farm.